# Unable to retreive metadata for 'MVCMusicStore.Models.Album'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have already had a look at some of the answers on here and tried google as well.  I am not sure whether the question has been answered and I simply don't understand it or if I am doing something differently to create a similar error.

Where I am at.  I have been learning C# and MVC for a few months slowly by working through tutorials, trying things and then going back to find another tutorial to try to understand the intricacies of the system.  So beginner is where I sit solidly.  So if I seem a  bit simple this is why.

I am currently working through the tutorial on ASP.NET [CLick Here for MVC Music Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNDq0.jpg) on creating a shopping cart application.  I am up to creating the StoreManagerController which is the first controller to be created using EF with views.  The tutorial is for an older version of VS than I am using, however, so far everything else I have been able to work through.

To date we have created our models, created a few views and controllers.  All fine and dandy.

To eliminate any potential issues I have:

-Built the project
- Cleaned the project
- Commented out the connection string in the web config file
- commented out the entity framework in the web config file

None of the above seem to be working for me...or I am doing them wrong.

The not helpful error is:

[Error and Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNDq0.jpg)

Sorry this forum doesn't allow me to enclose code properly with the two images.  Will post follow on with code.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
         AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

Comment: Album Model

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }

        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: So something lik this https://forums.asp.net/t/1876531.aspx?Unable+to+retrieve+metadata+for+MvcMusicStore+Models+Album+ doesn't cover it?

Comment: NB: If you are working through a version of MusicStore tutorial that is *older* than your VS version, there is probably an updated version of the tutorial for your VS version?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment from @ChrisFCarroll to your question, you might want to change your connection string to:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
 connectionString="Data
 Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"/>
```

This connection string is changing a DataSource from (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB to (LocalDb)\v11.0. According to [this](https://elanderson.net/2015/03/localdb-v11-0-or-mssqllocaldb/) blog post

> "“(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB” is the connection string used for SQL
>   Express 2014 and “(LocalDB)\v11.0” is used for SQL Express 2012."

Then you might want to delete and recreate your database.

Comment: ="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   At least I think I have.  I picked the V11.00 error ages back.

Comment: And the database3 is located in a server instance under V13.0 in server explorer...so pretty sure I am not having a virgin problem

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the webconfig file as I kept saying and after a lot of mucking about.  The problem was eventually traced to the Album model.

The process to diagnose was to download the sample application.

Create the controller using the ApplicationDbContext then convert to MusicStoreEntities by commenting out and pasting in from the sample code.  This then created an error to be thrown on the Album model.  After some more faffing about as I didnt completely understand the interweaving of the code yet, it turned out the demo was missing a line in the Album model.  Added via refactoring and all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your MusicStoreEntities class as following :

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists{ get; set; }
    }
}
```